# How to catch exeption in unit test and check it

Tags: magento2, php, unit-tests

I have a model class, that throw exception if some value is null. 
How I can test, that it condition is ok.

```
 $contact = $this->contactFactory->create()
            ->setEmail('testdelete@test.com')
            ->setFirstname('Pasha')
            ->setLastname('Doe')
            ->setPhone(1236547);
 $this->contactRepository->save($contact); //exception is here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using php code, try:

> if(isset($contact))
>        $this->contactRepository->save($contact);

or

> try { $this->contactRepository->save($contact); } catch